# When is while (--i) used?

Tags: javascript, operator-keyword, decrement

I understand that while loops will continue to run "While something is true"
But when would I use

```
while (--i)
```

I understand that this says "while decrements i is true"

I know for sure that my understanding of this statement is incorrect.

I hope someone can give me an example of when this would be used.

I'm thinking that it would be like an if statement that just keeps on happening when the i gets decreased.

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: Is there a difference between programming languages for this operator?
If so, javascript.

Comment: It is illegal syntax in Java and many other languages

Comment: `i` has to be defined somewhere. `--i` will resolve to 0 at some point, unless it is already under 0, and while sees 0 as false.

Comment: When you need it? This is a vacuous question.

Comment: Technically, no one needs it -- there are alternatives (see my answer below). I think it's largely a matter of preference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In JavaScript:

```
var i = 4;
while (--i) // try also i--
{
  alert("we still have time " + i);
}
```

In some languages **numbers** greater than 0 are considered **true**, when used as **booleans** (I think in C this will work). In this case (JavaScript as myf pointed) you will be iterating till the moment when i is no longer greater than 0. Try `--i` and `i--` to see the difference in the number of iterations.

In other languages like Java, C# as mention by a_horse_with_no_name you have to indicate this is a boolean operation e.g. `while ( --i > 0)`. What the C# compiler says is:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'

Comment: I like this answer. I'll up-vote when the OP says "Sorry, I meant to tag the language" :D And there it is...

Comment: This is a bit misleading: in JavaScript *only number zero is falsy*. `!!-1 // true` `!!0 // false`, `!!-1 // true`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I know my question was really vague. But I understood it.

Answer (score 0):

Count back to a `falsy` result, or more literal:

while the result of --i does not evaluate to something that would evaluate to false (i.e. 0), do something.

Answer (score 0):

You sometimes see

```
var i = 4;
while(--i) {
  // Code to repeat 4 times
}
```

as a more succinct way of writing

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4, i += 1) {
  // Code to repeat 4 times
}
```

But it's also potentially more confusing to read (especially if you don't know that zero is falsy in JavaScript). I usually prefer the latter form.